# How to understand intuitively the three relations about coordinate transformation?

Tags: coordinate-systems, group-theory

The question is related to the representation theory of group theory for physics. Generally, one can define the coordinate transformation $T$ by the following relation:
$$\vec{r}'=R(T)\vec{r}+\vec{t}(T)\equiv\{R(T)|\vec{t}(T)\}\vec{r} \tag{1}$$
in which $R(T)$ represents a rotation about an axis through the origin $O$ and $\vec{t}(T)$ a translation of $O$ to $O'$. The formula $(1)$ can be understand easily. However, based on it one can derive the follwoing relations:

$$\{R(T_1T_2)|\vec{t}(T_1T_2)\} =\{R(T_1)R(T_2)|R(T_1)\vec{t}(T_2)+\vec{t}(T_1)\} \tag{2}$$

$$\{R(T)|\vec{t}(T)\}^{-1}=\{R(T)^{-1}|-R(T)^{-1}\vec{t}(T)\} \tag{3}$$

$$\{R(T_1T_2)|\vec{t}(T_1T_2)\}^{-1}=\{R(T_2)|\vec{t}(T_2)\}^{-1}\{R(T_1)|\vec{t}(T_1)\}^{-1} \tag{3}$$

So how can I understand intuitively the three relations about coordinate transformation?